# how to create skin in dnn 5.0

Tags: dotnetnuke, skinning

I am working on dnn 5.04.04 and getting some problems in skinning.I want to create a new customized skin,How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Get started with [this](http://blog.theaccidentalgeek.com/post/2010/06/28/DotNetNuke-Skinning-101-%28Part-1%29.aspx) tutorial series. Also if you want, visit [OSDNNSKINS](http://osdnnskins.codeplex.com) which is having many free skins that are ready to use in your dnn site. You can use it for learning learning purpose as well.